# Write log messages to the log file in openscript

Tags: openscript

I need to write log messages to the log file instead of console in script.
By default few methods are provided by `openscript.info(), warn()`.
where did they configured to write messages to the console.
when I have written `info(message);` it's writing message to the console.
where is the `log4j.properties` configured? Do I need to override to write to log file?

Answer (score 0):

All log messages are stored in your OATS location, default in: C:\OracleATS\logs. Files are named "process_console_[timestamp].[hash].log"

However, if you want to create your own log file, I suggest to create a dedicated method, which uses built-in methods. In my code I did something like this:

```java
private String filePath = "c:/warnings.log";

public void saveLog(String message) throws Exception {

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss]");
    Date sysdate = new Date();

    String modifiedText = df.format(sysdate) + " " + message + "\n";

    Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), modifiedText.getBytes(),
            StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}

public void warning(String message) throws Exception {
    saveLog(message);
    warn(message);
}

public void run() throws Exception {
    warning("Test");
}
```